# "Piping" methods in methods chaining

Tags: php, yii, chaining

Lately I implemented this behavior for yii: https://github.com/garex/yii-pipe-behavior

It's main purpose is to allow methods chaining for methods, that are getters. Something in such style could be implemented in any other language/framework. It's more like syntactic sugar for fanats of method chaining.

From readme:

> For example owner has method *gimmeAll*, that returns array that we
>   want to transform by another owner`s method, let it be *toSomething*.
>   In old style we call:
>
> ```
> $bla = Something::create()->toSomething(Something::create()->one()->two()->three()->gimmeAll());
> ```
>
> But with this behavior we can do this in more elegant way:
>
> ```
> $bla = Something::create()->one()->two()->three()->pipe('gimmeAll')->unpipe('toSomething', '{r}');
> ```
>
> If unpiped method has single parameter, then we can omit '{r}'
>   parameter and call it like:
>
> ```
> $bla = Something::create()->one()->two()->three()->pipe('gimmeAll')->unpipe('toSomething');
> ```

### So my questions are:

1. Can it be really useful? I implemented this stuff in late night and
   still not sure.
2. Could it be a "bicycle"? May be such stuff exists in another lang/framework?

Comment: _Personal opinion_: I don't really like it when classes/methods/functions are called by strings. It is hard to find (let alone refactor) in most decent IDE's, making a hunt for bugs a bit tougher. _If_ it saves quite a lot of CPU cycles in building a new object, it is worth considering, but if it doesn't, doing something new with it deserves to be a new statement in my opinion.

Comment: @Wrikken I also incline to this. As a workaround this option can be implemented, but not as a behavior — only as method of parent class: Something::create()->bla->pipe('{r}')->someMethod()->toSomething('{r}'), where pipe() returns not owner, but wrapper, that passes all calls to owners. But this is something strange :)

Comment: thread @ yiiforum: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50448-%E2%80%9Cpiping%E2%80%9D-methods-in-methods-chaining/page__mode__show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the results and answers from [thread at yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50448-piping-methods-in-methods-chaining/page__mode__show)

No, it's not usefult and even superfluous. Some quotes from there:

> I think saving results in a variable and passing it to the other method is much
>   cleaner, readable, better supported by IDE's and just more sane.

```
class Something
{
        public function gimmeAllToSomething()
        {
                return $this->toSomething($this->gimmeAll());
        }
}

$bla = Something::create()->one()->two()->tree()->gimmeAllToSomething();
```

> It's a bit more code to type and test, but best programming practices aren't about typing less.

---

Currently in real scenario I also used gimmeAllToSomething() approach. So we can think about it as a door where you do not need to go.